# The button is not being clicked

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]I have created some button in the nav section down below but they are not working.
I tried creating new button in the nav but they are cant be clicked and the cursor wont change when hovered.

I am trying to toggle the dark theme and make the resume button work.

```
<nav className="p-8 mb-12 flex justify-between">
        <h1 className="text-xl space-x-5 dark:text-white">
          Developed by, <span className=" text-teal-500">__RSD</span>
        </h1>
        <ul className="flex items-center dark:text-white space-x-5">
          <label className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={mode === "dark"}
              className="sr-only peer"
              onChange={handleCheck}
            />
            <div
              onClick={toggleDarkMode}
              className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer  peer-focus:ring-green-300  peer-checked:after:translate-x-full
               peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute
                after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border 
               after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-gray-600"
            ></div>
            <span className="ml-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white text-black">
              Dark
            </span>
          </label>

          <li>
            <button>
              <a
                href="resume"
                download={resume}
                className=" bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
              >
                Resume
              </a>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>``
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Please share the code you have written so far

Comment: I have shareda code but i hope you will be able to see it.

Comment: you should share code as texts instead of images

Comment: Image is difficult to read , please share the code as text format instead

Comment: I hope the above code text helps